# Target iteration of a class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, iteration

How is it possible to select a certain iteration of a class with jQuery?

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="part-1-2">Some stuff</td>
    <td class="part-1-2">Some stuff</td>
    <td class="part-1-2">Some stuff</td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible to do something along the lines of:

```
$('part-1-2')[1] //Do stuff
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EQ](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector is the one the you need, and works like the arrays in the php.

```
$('.part-1-2').eq(1); // select the second link
```

Comment: Your example shows the `eq()` *function*, not selector. Correct link should be http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 2):

[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) is the selector you need:

```
$('.part-1-2:eq(1)')
```

Other useful index-based selectors include `:lt()`, `:gt()`, `:even` and `:odd`.